# PHP convert $_POST values to string

Tags: php

I'd like to be able to convert all post data to a string but keep only the values in a string variable.

So if my posted data looks like this:

```
Array ( [alloy] => Array ( [0] => K18 [1] => ) 
        [color] => Array ( [0] => Gold [1] => ) 
        [stone] => Array ( [0] => Diamond [1] => ) 
        [dimension] => Array ( [0] => 3cm [1] => ) 
        [button1] => Submit )
```

i'd like it to finally look like: $data = 'K18, color Gold, Diamond, 3cm';

I've tried serialize, imploding array, http_build_query but they're not what I need.

if it helps to get the whole idea, I'm collecting data from 4 groups of checkbox and radiobutton arrays and I'd like to put the selected values into a delimited string and save to my db.

Comment: But `POST` data ***is*** an array...

Comment: `serialize` or `json_encode()` sounds exactly like what you need. Where's the problem?

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about the data you are collecting and why something like `serialize` won't work?

Comment: If you need to individually access those checkbox/radio values, then DO NOT save them as a delimited string in your db. you'll just be opening yourself to a word of hurt and tedium.

Comment: Can you clarify what this means "convert all post data to an array but keep only the data in a variable"?

Comment: The easiest way is to do an implode(";",$arr) after you have cleared of the blank entries (either by assining a value to them or not). Preferrably you should serialize your data using json_encode() if you want to do searches on your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
$s = array();
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
  if (is_array($v)) {
    if ('color' === $k) {
      array_push($s, implode('', array($k, $v[0])));
    } else {
      array_push($s, $v[0]);
    }
  }
}
echo implode(', ', $s);
```

Comment: This works exactly how I had in mind. Many thanks!
Although I dont need the extra if('color'---$k) check, it was a simple mistype in my example.

Comment: I ran into a slight problem when selecting multiple checkboxes from the same checkboxes array, only the 1st ones are saved. Any way I can save them all?

Comment: @bikey77 sure, use `array_push($s, implode('', $v));`

Comment: I tried using this and got a NULL return. All I did was swap 'color' for my name 'attributes' which contains `string '{
    "device_maker" = unknown;
    "device_model" = Simulator;
    "first_visit" = "1387478168.109";
    "last_visit" = "1388355516.424";
    latitude = "37.78583526611328";
    locale = en;
    longitude = "-122.4064178466797";
    "opted_in" = 1;
    "opted_out" = 0;
    "os_platform" = "iPhone OS";
    "os_version" = "7.0.3";
    "this_visit" = "1387478168.109";
    "user_id" = 1;
}' (length=389)` So, I'm still not sure how to access this data programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little trick. When grouping use `name[]` instead of `name`. This way the $_POST["name"] variable will be an array, just as you want.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inputname[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="inputname[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="inputname[]" value="3" />
```

PHP

```
print_r($_POST['inputname']);
```

// output if all checked

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

**NOTE: The array will contain only the checked values**

Comment: My radios and checkboxes are already named like you suggest. Please read my updated (rephrased) question.